# PHP PDO spaces in the prepare placeholder

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have function for getting the user data from database

```
    function getUser($usernameOrEmail) {
        global $db;
        $stm = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :userData OR email = :userData");
        $stm->execute([ ":userData" => $usernameOrEmail ]);
        $row = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return ($row != null) ? $row[0] : false;
    }
```

The problem is when I pass username with spaces in it, for example "John Doe" then I am always getting "false" as a result even if I have record with that username in database. But if I try just to pass for example "John" and I have that record in db also, everything is fine...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='John Doe'` works, and that you're not inadvertently passing in `"John%20Doe"`?

Comment: I am 100% sure that I am passing string 'John Doe' because even when I try to hardcode it it doesn't work.

Comment: Simple: you can't reuse the same placeholder name in PDO.

You need to rename one of them and then add another named bind. I almost popped this in as an answer; I should have lol Edit: @tadman am surprised you didn't catch that ;-)

Comment: But if that is true then it shouldnt work just with one word parameter without spaces and it works.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't use PDO so much as advocate for it as a base-line for most people to use. It's got some fundamental flaws, like this, which really should be patched.

Comment: Would `:userData IN (username, email)` work?

Comment: @tadman Oh, I didn't know. Sorry, I took it that you did know. I should not have been so presumptuous.

Comment: You can use the same parameter name multiple times if `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` is on.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's one of those things that's easy to forget. PDO has a lot of irritating quirks and I'm not always keeping them front of mind. I only recommend it since it has fewer quirks than the alternatives.

Comment: @tadman I take it that you don't visit YCS's website neither ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not familiar with what that is.

Comment: @xcentric What does `var_dump($stm->execute([ ":userData" => $usernameOrEmail ])); exit;` return?